# Ionic 2 auth - Skip login page if there's an user on local storage

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have an Ionic 2 application that does an authentication on my Rails 5 backend. Once the user is logged, I store his informations on local storage.
So, once the user open the apps and he has already logged before, the login page should be skipped. I'm trying to do that on my `app.component` setting my root page depending on if there's information about the user on local storage or not, but the `storage.get` method appears to be asynchronous, so it is executing after my check, so it's always considering it false.

Any ideas how I could fix that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can set the root page after getting the value from the storage like this:

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
    @ViewChild(Nav) navCtrl: Nav;

    public rootPage; // Just declare the property, don't set a value here

    constructor(...) {
      this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        Splashscreen.hide();

        // Get the status from the storage
        this.storage.get('login:status').then(loggedIn => {
          this.rootPage = loggedIn ? HomePage : LoginPage;
        });
      });
    }

}
```

In this case, if the user is already logged in, the root page will be the HomePage, and if it's not logged in, the LoginPage.

Comment: Yeah, my problem was that I used that get function on a service... so I had to subscribe to that function and then execute the code. But I'm really grateful, you helped a lot! =)

Comment: You can create Event also when the user login... and in app.component you check whether that login event has been published or not

Comment: Glad to help @RonanLopes :) I just included the get in the same app.component to give you the overall idea, but yes, this should definitely be included in a service

Comment: This worked like a charm. I had to read it twice because I was setting the root page in the declaration of rootPage which caused the login screen to flash for a few seconds. Great answer!

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped @DevShadow :)

Comment: using this code in similar way , giving me error cordova not available, any fixes for that?

Comment: @ShilpiJaiswal That related to a Cordova plugin that you're trying to use in the browser, so that errors is *not* related to setting the `rootPage` dynamically. What Cordova plugins are you using?

Comment: I have got solution for my problem enclosed my code in condition 
 if(this.platform.is('cordova')) { } and its working fine.