# Load home page as landing page user Id stored in local storage

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

In my ionic app(v-4), After **login** i am storing the `user_id` in the `local storage` like this:

```
onLogin(){
 localStorage.setItem('user_id',  this.loginForm.user_id);
}
```

- And i have made `login page` as `landing page`, After `login page` the user will be routed `home page`. This routing is working fine.
- But again if the user opens the `app` It should show `home page` as landing page since the app already stored the `user_id` in its `local storage`.

**CODE**

**app.component.html**

```
<ion-router-outlet main></ion-router-outlet>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private statusBar: StatusBar
  ) {
    this.initializeApp();
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
    });
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule ,
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**app.routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomePageModule'
  },
  { path: 'login', loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginPageModule' },
  { path: 'my-profile', loadChildren: './my-profile/my-profile.module#MyProfilePageModule' },
  { path: 'appointments', loadChildren: './appointments/appointments.module#AppointmentsPageModule' },
  { path: 'request-acceptance', loadChildren: './request-acceptance/request-acceptance.module#RequestAcceptancePageModule' },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I found this similar **[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43377594/ionic-2-auth-skip-login-page-if-theres-an-user-on-local-storage)** but i am unable to do it my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implmement a guard which redirect to home page if the user is logged in 
Try this:

**create a guard in src/guard/auth.guard.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private router:Router,
  ){}
  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
      if(localStorage.getItem('user_id') != undefined || null){
        return true;
      }else{
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        return false;
      }
  }
}
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private statusBar: StatusBar
  ) {
    this.initializeApp();
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
    });
    if (localStorage.getItem("user_id") != undefined || null) {
      this.router.navigate(['/home']);
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['/login'])
    }
  }
}
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import {AuthGuard} from './guard/auth.guard'; //add this

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomePageModule',canActivate:[AuthGuard]  //Use canActive:[AuthGuard] to protect routing if user is not logged in.
  },
  { path: 'login', loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginPageModule' },
  { path: 'my-profile', loadChildren: './my-profile/my-profile.module#MyProfilePageModule'},
  { path: 'appointments', loadChildren: './appointments/appointments.module#AppointmentsPageModule' },
  { path: 'request-acceptance', loadChildren: './request-acceptance/request-acceptance.module#RequestAcceptancePageModule' },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import {AuthGuard} from './guard/auth.guard'; //add this

import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule ,
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    AuthGuard, //add this
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering,Let me try your solution...:)

Comment: It is not allowing the user  to route to `home page` if he is not logged in, This is fine. But if he is logged `home page` should be the landing page, How can i achieve this requirement.

Comment: I have edited my answer in 'app.component.ts', please check.

Answer (score 1):

Set Your Login Component as default page. In Login Component

```
ngOninit(){
if(localStorage.getItem('user_id') != undefined || null){
    //Redirect to Homepage
}
else{
    //do nothing
   }
}
```

When you load your first page (i.e) login page. It will check whether you have login id stored in local storage as we wrote condition in Oninit of landing page. If yes, It will automatically redirects to your homepage and If no, then it remains in same page.

Comment: This is fine for a simple case, but your app can only load 2 main routes now. If you wanted to email a link to let's say www.myapp.com/register anyone clicking it would see your homepage, and not your register page.